# Display simple product attribute set with values in shopping cart and order page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, sales-order, invoice, shopping-cart

I want to display all the attributes of product attribute set on shopping cart page and sales order,invoice pages only for simple products.Suggest me some solution.

I have used the following code.

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?> 
<?php //echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
$_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute‌​_code')->getStoreLab‌​el();
```

I want **all the attributes of product from its attribute set** and **not particular attribute using attribute code.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this, But you can get all attribute here

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
    ->getItems();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
    echo $attribute->getAttributecode();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
}
```

Based on this you can load your attribute set and product type

Comment: thanks for your answer but how to get values please give syntax.

Comment: What values you want

Comment: values of all attributes of simple  product on shopping cart page